# My one hot encoder function only allows 2/3 columns rather 4

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

A background - I am trying to do Image classification with Convolutional Neural Networks using Data Augmentation. Previously, I used this function to encode 3 labels. Now I am trying to add one more label but it can't form the confusion matrix since the inverse transform doesn't seem to work on the predicted and test labels.

Code for encoding labels :

```
def encode_data(y_train, y_test):
    from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
    enc = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
    y_train = enc.fit_transform(y_train.reshape(-1, 1))
    y_test = enc.transform(y_test.reshape(-1, 1))
    return y_train, y_test
```

My evaluate model function which I use to form my confusion matrix

```
def evaluate_model(X_test, y_test, model):
    import seaborn as sns
    from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
    
    y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
    res = np.zeros_like(y_pred)
    for i in range(len(np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1))):
        res[i, np.argmax(y_pred,axis=1)[i]]=1
    y_pred = res
    cm = confusion_matrix(enc.inverse_transform(y_test), enc.inverse_transform(y_pred))
    ax=sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True)
    plt.xlabel('Predicted')
    plt.ylabel('Truth')
    print(classification_report(enc.inverse_transform(y_test), 
    enc.inverse_transform(y_pred), zero_division=0))
```

It would be great if someone could help me with this. I have been racking my brains over it for days now.

The error looks like :  File "C:\Users\ajayr\anaconda3\envs\ML4ENG_lab\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing_encoders.py", line 456, in inverse_transform
raise ValueError(msg.format(n_transformed_features, X.shape[1]))
ValueError: Shape of the passed X data is not correct. Expected 3 columns, got 4.

Comment: From just what you've shown, the `enc` doesn't live outside the scope of the two functions, so it should fail with a NameError instead.  Did you create the previous encoder in the global scope?

Comment: Hello, yes I did.
enc = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)

Comment: Also an update - I did encode and transform my input and test with this function but I use the inverse transform with the global enc. I didn't think it made a difference, does it?

Comment: Never mind! It was the issue! Thank you so much!!!!